# Relations and joins between tables with primary key clustered index

Tags: sql, join

Created two tables using PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED with **identity** and **Date** ON partition because a task splits and truncates partitions older that 30 days. keeping only the recent records.

I have a special field to correlate the tables, but the **joins** are painfully slow even with indexes. Could you suggest how to optimize?

Next the tables and the Join statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Redeem](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ticket] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CorrelationTicket] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Redeem fields here...]
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Redeem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CreatedDate] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
ON myPS([CreatedDate]);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Redeem_CorrelationTicket]
ON [dbo].[Redeem]([CreatedDate] ASC, [CorrelationTicket] ASC)
ON [myPS] ([CreatedDate]);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Validate](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ticket] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CorrelationTicket] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Validate fields here...]
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Validate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CreatedDate] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
ON myPS([CreatedDate]);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Validate_CorrelationTicket]
ON [dbo].[Validate]([CreatedDate] ASC, [CorrelationTicket] ASC)
ON [myPS] ([CreatedDate]);
```

And this is the Join:

```
SELECT top 100
    v.*,
    r.*
from 
    Validate v
LEFT OUTER join Redeem r
    on v.CorrelationTicket = r.CorrelationTicket
ORDER BY v.CreatedDate DESC
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used (perhaps SQL Server?), to get better and correct attention. (Lots of non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: why is your index on both columns? ID is already unique, i would think your query would benefit more from an index ***only*** on `CorrelationTicket` rather than both `CorrelationTicket` and `CreatedDate`  Also note, you're doing an `order by` meaning, in order to get the top 100, the entire result set needs to be ordered first. Also for what reason are you left joining over inner?  You simply need everything from validate?  I believe generally speaking `inner` join is faster than non

Comment: Post the query plan.

Comment: Well your join is on a column which is not in an index with the primary position. So look at the explain plan and you will certainly have a index scan or table scan to be able to do the join.

Comment: Short answer is either 1) Add an index on `CreatedDate DESC`, and/or 2) Add an index to both tables with `CorrelationTicket` as the *first* (or only) column.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Krintner!

The problem was the ORDER BY as you suggested. it was sorting the entire result set (not sure why).
I do need to sort, but changing the Index to be DESC did the trick.

I also follow the recommendation and use only CorrelationTicket in the INDEX.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_Redeem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CreatedDate] DESC,
    [Id] DESC
)
```